# Why am I getting weird Normal colors when baking in Substance Painter?

Tags: normal-map

I am trying to bake a simple shape but I am facing issues when the bake is done. The normal colors look very distorted and I feel that if i use it in any game engine, it'll be a mess. Are these distortions fine or is there any issue i can fix?
[image: Distorted normal colors in substance painter AFTER baking]

The baked model looks fine.[image]

Smoothed low poly to minimize seams after the bake
[image: Smoothed low poly to minimize seams after the bake]

Shouldn't Flat faces have a constant color?
[image: Normal Map]

Comment: Hello ! Which seams do you want to minimize exactly with smoothing your mesh ?

Comment: @Gorgious Hi! The seams that pop up here: https://imgur.com/Y59xghN
This is baked on a flat shaded low poly.

Comment: If you shade smooth the low-poly before baking it will distort the normal map

Comment: @moonboots In that case, what do I do to minimize the seams and also get good normals?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by minimizing the seams, do you want to have rounder edges? In that case you need to create a bevel on the low-poly, you can't create the illusion of a bevel with a normal map if this is what you were trying

Comment: Got it! I'll just bevel all low poly objects then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you shade smooth the low-poly before baking it will distort the normal map. If your goal is to create rounder edges on your low-poly you need to bevel them, you can't create the illusion of bevelled edges if they are sharp.